# cannot import name 'core' from partially initialized module 'tensorflow_datasets' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, python-import, jupyter-lab

I am trying to import tensorflow in jupyter notebook as in

```
import time
import keras_cv
from tensorflow import keras
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

after restarting and having a fresh kernel and then running the block first error it shows is:

```
Using TensorFlow backend
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [1], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 import time
----> 2 import keras_cv
      3 from tensorflow import keras
      4 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\keras_cv\__init__.py:8, in <module>
      1 """DO NOT EDIT.
      2 
      3 This file was autogenerated. Do not edit it by hand,
      4 since your modifications would be overwritten.
      5 """
----> 8 from keras_cv import bounding_box
      9 from keras_cv import callbacks
     10 from keras_cv import core

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\keras_cv\bounding_box\__init__.py:8, in <module>
      1 """DO NOT EDIT.
      2 
      3 This file was autogenerated. Do not edit it by hand,
      4 since your modifications would be overwritten.
      5 """
----> 8 from keras_cv.src.bounding_box.converters import convert_format
      9 from keras_cv.src.bounding_box.ensure_tensor import ensure_tensor
     10 from keras_cv.src.bounding_box.formats import CENTER_XYWH

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\keras_cv\src\__init__.py:32, in <module>
     30 from keras_cv.src import bounding_box
     31 from keras_cv.src import callbacks
---> 32 from keras_cv.src import datasets
     33 from keras_cv.src import layers
     34 from keras_cv.src import losses

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\keras_cv\src\datasets\__init__.py:14, in <module>
      1 # Copyright 2022 The KerasCV Authors
      2 #
      3 # Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
   (...)
     12 # See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     13 # limitations under the License.
---> 14 from keras_cv.src.datasets import pascal_voc

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\keras_cv\src\datasets\pascal_voc\__init__.py:14, in <module>
      1 # Copyright 2022 The KerasCV Authors
      2 #
      3 # Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
   (...)
     12 # See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     13 # limitations under the License.
---> 14 from keras_cv.src.datasets.pascal_voc.load import load

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\keras_cv\src\datasets\pascal_voc\load.py:16, in <module>
      1 # Copyright 2022 The KerasCV Authors
      2 #
      3 # Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
   (...)
     12 # See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     13 # limitations under the License.
     15 import tensorflow as tf
---> 16 import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
     18 from keras_cv.src import bounding_box
     19 from keras_cv.src.api_export import keras_cv_export

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\__init__.py:43, in <module>
     41 _TIMESTAMP_IMPORT_STARTS = time.time()
     42 from absl import logging
---> 43 import tensorflow_datasets.core.logging as _tfds_logging
     44 from tensorflow_datasets.core.logging import call_metadata as _call_metadata
     46 _metadata = _call_metadata.CallMetadata()

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\core\__init__.py:22, in <module>
     18 # Allow to use `tfds.core.Path` in dataset implementation which seems more
     19 # natural than having to import a third party module.
     20 from etils.epath import Path
---> 22 from tensorflow_datasets.core import community
     23 from tensorflow_datasets.core.dataset_builder import BeamBasedBuilder
     24 from tensorflow_datasets.core.dataset_builder import BuilderConfig

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\core\community\__init__.py:18, in <module>
      1 # coding=utf-8
      2 # Copyright 2023 The TensorFlow Datasets Authors.
      3 #
   (...)
     13 # See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     14 # limitations under the License.
     16 """Community dataset API."""
---> 18 from tensorflow_datasets.core.community.huggingface_wrapper import mock_builtin_to_use_gfile
     19 from tensorflow_datasets.core.community.huggingface_wrapper import mock_huggingface_import
     20 from tensorflow_datasets.core.community.load import builder_cls_from_module

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\core\community\huggingface_wrapper.py:31, in <module>
     28 from unittest import mock
     30 from etils import epath
---> 31 from tensorflow_datasets.core import dataset_builder
     32 from tensorflow_datasets.core import dataset_info
     33 from tensorflow_datasets.core import download

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\core\dataset_builder.py:44, in <module>
     42 from tensorflow_datasets.core import reader as reader_lib
     43 from tensorflow_datasets.core import registered
---> 44 from tensorflow_datasets.core import split_builder as split_builder_lib
     45 from tensorflow_datasets.core import splits as splits_lib
     46 from tensorflow_datasets.core import tf_compat

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\core\split_builder.py:37, in <module>
     35 from tensorflow_datasets.core import splits as splits_lib
     36 from tensorflow_datasets.core import utils
---> 37 from tensorflow_datasets.core import writer as writer_lib
     38 from tensorflow_datasets.core.utils import shard_utils
     40 if typing.TYPE_CHECKING:

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\core\writer.py:33, in <module>
     31 from tensorflow_datasets.core import lazy_imports_lib
     32 from tensorflow_datasets.core import naming
---> 33 from tensorflow_datasets.core import shuffle
     34 from tensorflow_datasets.core import utils
     35 from tensorflow_datasets.core.utils import file_utils

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\core\shuffle.py:20, in <module>
     18 import math
     19 import os
---> 20 import resource
     21 import struct
     22 from typing import Iterator, List, Optional

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'resource'
```

With the same kernel, if I run the block again (using CTRL+ENTER) it shows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [2], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 import time
----> 2 import keras_cv
      3 from tensorflow import keras
      4 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\keras_cv\__init__.py:11, in <module>
      9 from keras_cv import callbacks
     10 from keras_cv import core
---> 11 from keras_cv import datasets
     12 from keras_cv import keypoint
     13 from keras_cv import layers

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\keras_cv\datasets\__init__.py:8, in <module>
      1 """DO NOT EDIT.
      2 
      3 This file was autogenerated. Do not edit it by hand,
      4 since your modifications would be overwritten.
      5 """
----> 8 from keras_cv.datasets import imagenet
      9 from keras_cv.datasets import pascal_voc
     10 from keras_cv.datasets import waymo

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\keras_cv\datasets\imagenet\__init__.py:8, in <module>
      1 """DO NOT EDIT.
      2 
      3 This file was autogenerated. Do not edit it by hand,
      4 since your modifications would be overwritten.
      5 """
----> 8 from keras_cv.src.datasets.imagenet.load import load

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\keras_cv\src\__init__.py:32, in <module>
     30 from keras_cv.src import bounding_box
     31 from keras_cv.src import callbacks
---> 32 from keras_cv.src import datasets
     33 from keras_cv.src import layers
     34 from keras_cv.src import losses

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\keras_cv\src\datasets\__init__.py:14, in <module>
      1 # Copyright 2022 The KerasCV Authors
      2 #
      3 # Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
   (...)
     12 # See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     13 # limitations under the License.
---> 14 from keras_cv.src.datasets import pascal_voc

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\keras_cv\src\datasets\pascal_voc\__init__.py:14, in <module>
      1 # Copyright 2022 The KerasCV Authors
      2 #
      3 # Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
   (...)
     12 # See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     13 # limitations under the License.
---> 14 from keras_cv.src.datasets.pascal_voc.load import load

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\keras_cv\src\datasets\pascal_voc\load.py:16, in <module>
      1 # Copyright 2022 The KerasCV Authors
      2 #
      3 # Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
   (...)
     12 # See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     13 # limitations under the License.
     15 import tensorflow as tf
---> 16 import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
     18 from keras_cv.src import bounding_box
     19 from keras_cv.src.api_export import keras_cv_export

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\__init__.py:43, in <module>
     41 _TIMESTAMP_IMPORT_STARTS = time.time()
     42 from absl import logging
---> 43 import tensorflow_datasets.core.logging as _tfds_logging
     44 from tensorflow_datasets.core.logging import call_metadata as _call_metadata
     46 _metadata = _call_metadata.CallMetadata()

ImportError: cannot import name 'core' from partially initialized module 'tensorflow_datasets' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\ROHIT\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\__init__.py)
```

I have resource and tensorflow already installed through pip but this issue still persists

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/datasets/issues/5097

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was running into the same issue and it was fixed by installing the nightly build,

```
pip install tfds-nightly
```

It imports the same, so make sure to uninstall the regular tensorflow-datasets. If that doesn't work, maybe try to rebuild your environment/venv/etc.

Package Versions:

```
Python: 3.9
tensorflow: 2.13.0
tfds-nightly: 4.9.3.dev202309250044
```

Comment: Thanks man. It worked perfectly fine. What does it do to fix the issue?

Comment: @Rohit Initially I was getting two errors, one was for a missing resource folder, which is present in Linux but not Windows (I'm working in Windows). The other was this core, issue which I'm assuming there was something problematic in the structure of the core directory in the package, or a weird import somewhere. Might also be a windows specific problem, which evidently was caught at some point in the daily build.

Comment: I see. Thanks @Ronen

Comment: Ya, it works for me. Thanks. Just, the problem is that it is showing the download status multiple times.